# How to make Windows Phone web search return apps suggestion?

Tags: windows-phone-7, search, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-8

I can't find any information on this because I don't even know what it's called. When someone does a web search on Windows Phone, it will return some app results at the top of the page. What is this called? If I knew the term, I'm sure I could find the info I need to do it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The google term you're looking for is "Search Extensiblity" and it's actually a WP7.5 ("Mango") feature and not a WP8 feature. Basically, You'll need to expose a humongous structured XML document for Bing server to index. Bing will then tell WP8 which apps have relevant results for the current search term based on your structure XML data.

MSDN docs @ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202969(VS.92).aspx

MSDN Webcast @ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsmobile/hh369941.aspx